# RUN microdnf install google-chrome-stable results in 'cannot be verified and repo google-chrome is GPG enabled'

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, dockerfile, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following Dockerfile

```
ARG CHROME_VERSION=116.0.5845.96-1
ADD google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install -y google-chrome-stable-$CHROME_VERSION \
    && sed -i 's/"$HERE\/chrome"/"$HERE\/chrome" --no-sandbox/g' /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
```

and I also have the file google-chrome.repo:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

This used to work but now I get:

```
#8 48.09 Downloading packages...
#8 91.38 error: package google-chrome-stable-116.0.5845.96-1.x86_64 cannot be verified and repo google-chrome is GPG enabled: /var/cache/yum/metadata/google-chrome-8-x86_64/packages/google-chrome-stable-116.0.5845.96-1.x86_64.rpm could not be verified.
#8 91.38 /var/cache/yum/metadata/google-chrome-8-x86_64/packages/google-chrome-stable-116.0.5845.96-1.x86_64.rpm:  digest:  SIGNATURE:  NOT OK
```

I know Google recently changed the locaiton of the Google chrome. But, does anyone know how to:

1. not require the check in the first place?
2. fix it so that can verify the download (maybe by changing google-chrome.repo?)

My thought is that somehow the following is wrong:

```
[google-chrome]
name=google-chrome
baseurl=http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/rpm/stable/x86_64
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and importing the key into rpm got it working:

Dockerfile:

```
COPY google-chrome.repo /etc/yum.repos.d/google-chrome.repo
RUN microdnf install wget --assumeyes
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub
RUN rpm --import linux_signing_key.pub
RUN microdnf install google-chrome-stable --assumeyes
```

Where `google-chrome.repo` is identically what you posted.

Commands came from [these docs](https://www.google.com/linuxrepositories/)